# oAuth 2.0 Library for iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 and need a oAuth library. From my searches I found [AFOAuth2Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client) but its still AF1.0 dependent. Are there any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: If you found the answer useful, accept it else let us know what you ended up using.

Comment: some people on github have decided to update the library themselves, works great now

[link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55)

Comment: How about [OAuth2Client](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client)?

Comment: Any updates @George L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by the community on [the github repo](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55#commits-pushed-5ed7a6e) for theAFOAuth2Client. No one has officially made the merge, but these fixes allow the library to work perfectly.